# Qt error when trying to use GPU rendering for a robotics simulator on headless machine

Tags: software-installation, python, qt, opengl, qt5

I'm trying to get a robotics simulator (https://github.com/stepjam/PyRep) working on a remote headless machine with GPU rendering. I've followed the installation instructions, and can run an example script using xvfb:
`xvfb-run python examples/single_task_rl.py`
However, this doesn't use GPU for rendering, making the program execution very slow.

If I run the script without xvfb using the command `python examples/single_task_rl.py`, I get the following error related to Qt:

```
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display 
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/path/to/CoppeliaSim_Edu_V4_1_0_Ubuntu18_04/" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, webgl, xcb.

Aborted (core dumped)
```

I don't have experience with Qt, so not sure which of these plugins I need to choose, and how to fix the error related to loading the plugin. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The `/path/to/...` part looks suspicious. It seems it is looking in the wrong place. Have you edited your bashrc file to include the actual installation location as explained?

Comment: I modified that bit manually while posting the question -- the actual error message has the correct path to the root directory of CoppeliaSim,